# Is there a NOOP rule that can be used in a css file?

Tags: css, minify

I'm working on some refactoring of legacy code to move styles to a stylesheet file from the html. Our build process runs the stylesheet css files through the YUI compresser minifier. Which in its efficiency strips out empty `.selector { }` styles see - [YuiDoc's No empty declarations section](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/css.html#syntax-77922d6769234e7a2fd537a7096d671c).

The issue arises when in some places the code finds and modifies stylesheet rules, but it can't find the rules that have been minified/stripped. Is there a noop rule they would not effect any rendering but would keep the effectively empty rule in the stylesheet?

Comment: How about a non-existent property: `foo:bar;`. CSS just ignores these anyways.

Comment: Would the CSS still validate with bogus properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [W3C CSS2 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#vendor-keywords)

> In CSS, identifiers may begin with '-' (dash) or '_' (underscore).
>   Keywords and property names beginning with -' or '_' are reserved for
>   vendor-specific extensions

So you could create your own property say for example `-custom-noop: noop;` without the validator complaining too much. You might however have some problems with older browsers ignoring other rules in a block if you use this.

Edit:
You might also have some luck with this syntax:

```
.someclass{
    /*! Keep Me */
}
```

Comments like this are kept in after compressing so it might work for keeping the block the comment is inside. Note that after compression the `!` is stripped so you will need to add it back each time you compress it.

Comment: No problems. Just for completeness, did you try both methods and did they both work?

Comment: I tried the !comment which works and seemed to be the better solution, given the yui doc. The -custom-noop:noop my concern was as mentioned about what older browsers would do with it.  I tried various options on the online tool here - http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: The ```/*! Keep Me */``` option worked for me. I also tried ```display: initial;``` in every element but that didn't work.